# Pie chart legend with multiple lines of text in R

Tags: r, legend, pie-chart

I am attempting to use the following code to split my long line of text into multiple lines in the legend of a pie chart. The current code creates a legend with a lot of white space and the text runs over the box. The box is also over the pie chart. What am I doing wrong?

```
v4_class_combined_slices <- c(27, 121, 27)
v4_class_combined_labels <- c("Bacteroidia", "Clostridia", "Actinobacteria/Coriobacteriia/\n4C0d.2/Bacilli/Erysipelotrichi/\nBetaproteobacteria/Gammaproteobacteria/\nMollicutes/RF3")
piepercent <- round(100*v4_class_combined_slices/sum(v4_class_combined_slices), 1)
piepercent2 <- paste(piepercent, sep = " ", "%")
pie(v4_class_combined_slices, labels = piepercent2, col = rainbow(3))
legend("topright", v4_class_combined_labels, cex = 0.9, text.width = 1.5, yjust = 0, fill = rainbow(length(v4_class_combined_labels)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to adjust the cex and text.width.

legend("topright", v4_class_combined_labels, cex = 0.4, text.width = 1.0, yjust = 0.0, fill = rainbow(length(v4_class_combined_labels)))

Comment: Hmm that didn't work for me. I still have the same problem. See the image: https://imgur.com/a/kw9oFOv

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Code for the Plot

It will work.I have used ggplot2, ggrepel library. Make sure you install
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4ZcB.png

Comment: Greetings! It's not advisable to share a screenshot of your code. It is better to simply add it here. That way people can just copy and paste your code into their respective scripts.